# After normal shutdown, pc doesn't start/boot, leds and fans light/spin for a second

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

Sometimes after shutting my pc down in the evening and starting it back up in the morning the pc will not boot. The fans spin for a second, LEDs light up also for a second but the pc stays off.

While the LEDs of the RAM will stay on, the power button is unresponsive (Case and Motherboard). The only way to reset my pc is to drain the PSU with the main switch on the PSU.

After that it boots up then I try it a second time, but sometimes i need more attempts to successfully boot. (Doing the same steps above, Drain PSU, etc.)

I switched the Motherboard and CPU after one died (Didn't have spare parts to troubleshoot them). Also unplugged my corsair commander pro after USB issues.

My current setup is

- MB Asus x570 PRO
- CPU AMD Ryzen 7 5700x
- GPU EVGA RTX 3070 XC3 Ultra
- PSU Bitfenix Whisper M 650w Gold (bought 01/18)

I hope I have listed everything, if not I'm happy to provide more informations.

Comment: How do you shut down? If you're using Sleep, try Hibernation or full Shutdown. Also, turn off Fast Boot in BIOS. These are to avoid leaving the PC in some undefined state if it turns *itself* off after an extended time.

Comment: Hey, already shutting it completely every time and turned fast boot off while configured it in the first boot after assembling.